# PayPal REST PHP API Direct Payment

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

I am trying to use PayPal Rest API in PHP for Direct Payment on my website (and I am trying to do this as a third-party to another company).

I got the code from the developer.paypal.com website for authentication:

```
$sdkConfig = array(
    "mode" => "sandbox"
);

$cred = new OAuthTokenCredential("...","...", $sdkConfig);
```

Replacing "sandbox" with "live" when I finish testing.

The question in, what goes in place of ... ?  These two codes are generated from the PayPal Developer REST Playground site by clicking on API Credentials.  So I do not simply place the client ID and client secret in for "..." in the two arguments, correct?

Am I able to generate these codes within the php somehow?

Also, using this as third party, do I require different authentication codes, do I use a different client id and password for the third-party, do I use mine?

I have not been able to find any information regarding differing between using my own paypal account or referring payment to the actual merchant as a third party.  I've search around paypal's developer site, api site, and google with no luck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong, you should put your client ID and cliente secret
https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Auth/OAuthTokenCredential.php

```
public function __construct($clientId, $clientSecret) {
            $this->clientId = $clientId;
            $this->clientSecret = $clientSecret;                
    }
```

Comment: I see so then I use $cred = $auth->getAccessToken().